# Lookup Fields Showing up Blank for Guest User in Screen Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, guest-user

I have a screen flow that is being used on a public site. Everything in the flow is working correctly, except there are two lookup fields that are showing blank (no label or placeholder, and the field isn't usable). For reference, these are fields on the Contact object that are lookups for the Account object.

I have already confirmed the following:

- Read/Write access to Contact and Account objects
- Read/Write on all fields in field-level security
- Enabled access to flow
- Enabled access to site standard lookup and search pages
- Updated flow to run as System Context Without Sharing–Access All Data

Any ideas on what else I am missing here?

Here is how the field is showing up.
[image]

Comment: Your confirmation was done against the Guest User profile?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, I did.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you resolved it or not?